# WebSphere 7 password recovery

Tags: password-recovery, websphere, was7

On my local box I have RAD 7.5 and WebSphere 7.

When I run the administrative console it asks me for the username/password.
I tried all the default password/users combinations wasadmin/wasadmin wasadmin/wsadmin and so on an none of the works.

How do I recover my password/username?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Similar question - same answer:

  http://serverfault.com/questions/423621/how-to-change-ibm-websphere-network-deployment-passwords/631763#631763

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.

[LINK](http://java-x.blogspot.com/2005_12_01_archive.html)

Answer (score 0):

See IBM's guide  [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=180&context=SSEQTP&q1=disable+global+security+security.xml&uid=swg21105430&loc=en_US&cs=utf-8&lang=en)