# How to change IBM WebSphere Network deployment passwords?

Tags: password, ibm, websphere

How i can change the following for IBM WebSphere Network Deployment :

1- Deployment Manager Administrative console password

2- Application Server Password

Note : OS is UNIX-AIX

Comment: Can you no longer log into the console? Also, what version of WebSphere?

Comment: What user repository are you using ?

Comment: Yes , I cannot login to Administration console , WAS version is 7.0.11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can change your password depends on the repository used. However you can try to deactivate security by issuing

```
wsadmin -conntype NONE
wsasmin>securityoff
wsadmin>$AdminConfig save
```

Restart your deployment manager afterwards. However turning your security off opens also the applications deployed in Websphere.

Alternatively you could try to [decode the password](http://www.devops-insight.com/2014/08/how-to-decode-websphere-passwords.html).